# Does the expression "find it never enough to..." exist?

Tags: expressions

I was writing this sentence in an essay:

> They ***find it never enough to** emphasise* the importance of unity in their communal life.

Then I realised that I was not sure of this phrase and I looked it up on Google, but the hits I have found mostly read: *find **it's** never enough to ...*.

Does the expression I used sound awkward? Should I consider another way of saying this?

Comment: In Google Books I'm seeing just *find **it's** never enough* and *never find **it** enough*.

Comment: _Find_ can govern _to be_-deletion. _She finds it tedious having to take the bus_.

Comment: @DjinTonic Yes, I have stated that in the OP, although I have not specified it was Google books results.

Comment: I was just confirming it and pointing out that I didn't see *find it never enough*.

Comment: "They **cannot emphasize enough** the importance..." or "They **never stop emphasizing** the importance..."

Answer (score 1):

The most common construction is the following, where what is never enough is the intensity of the  emphasis, instead of the fact of emphasizing, as in the sentence under scrutiny.

- They find  that they never emphasize enough the importance of unity in their communal life.

If you wanted to focus on the fact of emphasizing, it seems that it is better to retain the verb "to be".

- They find that it is never enough (merely) to  emphasise the importance of unity in their communal life.

Comment: Yes, your second variant seems the closest to what I was trying to express. So basically, what I have written is not acceptable right?

Comment: @fev I can't say that it is not acceptable; it just doesn't feel to me like a usual construction, and so as to be safe, I'd add the verb.